# Unexpected Alert Open Causes Error in Behat/Mink Test

Tags: php, selenium-chromedriver, behat, mink

In my Behat test I click a link on the page that causes an alert to emerge, which I want to accept/press OK. I can't seem to deal with the alert because it causes an error that stops my tests:

> ```
>  unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure you want to delete this item?}
>    (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.96): Are you sure you want to delete this item?
>  Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>  System info: host: 'b4201ea64648', ip: '172.20.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.39-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_275'
>  Driver info: driver.version: unknown (WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpen)
> ```

Feature file:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: ...
    ...
    And I do something
```

Context file:

```php
use PaulGibbs\WordpressBehatExtension\Context\RawWordpressContext;
class MyCuteContext extends RawWordpressContext {
    /**
     * @Given /^I do something$/
     */
    public function iDoSomething()
    {
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

        ...

        $page->find(
            "css",
            "tbody > tr:nth-child(1)..."
        )->press();
    }
}
```

I don't seem to have access to a `accept_alert` function which I see is the advice when I search for this error. I've tried adding different variations of `$this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert();` which others online have advised with no luck. This line of code in particular gives me a grey squiggly in PHPStorm (underneath the `getWebDriverSession` portion)

> "Potentially polymorphic call. The code may be inoperable depending on the actual class instance passed as the argument."

My mink settings in `behat.yml` are

```
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://nginx/
      # Use goutte (basic PHP browser, super fast) as the default driver.
      default_session: headless
      # Tag features/scenarios with @javascript to use the selenium2 driver.
      javascript_session: selenium2
      browser_name: chrome
      #browser_name: firefox
      selenium2:
        wd_host: http://browser:4444/wd/hub
        #capabilities: { "browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", 'chrome': {'switches':['--no-sandbox', '--headless']}}
      sessions:
        headless:
          goutte:
            guzzle_parameters:
              verify: false
```

How can I accept/click OK on the alert that emerges?